# Start Javascript audio according to the time

Tags: javascript

I installed the following JS library and I'm using the "player" samples.
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js

Do you have any idea how to start the audio based on the time? I saw in the readme that they say to use the URL method with the seek parameter but I don't want to use a parameter in the URL but I want the time (in minutes or seconds) to be calculated when the site is accessed and for the audio to be started at that precise point.

I previously used this JS and it worked correctly:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "MI24H.mp3";
ORA_ATTUALE_IN_SECONDI=(new Date().getHours()*60*60)+(new Date().getMinutes()*60)+(new Date().getSeconds());
audio.currentTime = ORA_ATTUALE_IN_SECONDI
audio.play();
function playAudio() {
audio.play();
}
```

Comment: For debugging, it would be helpful if you share a working page (jsbin / jsfiddle).

Comment: https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/

The code is identical to this page. I haven't changed anything yet.

Only you see it better here that the code is not minimized: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/master/examples/player


I wanted to understand how to start the audio (by clicking on the play) based on the time.
I'm using a 24h MP3 file and with the code I posted above it worked. Now let me understand how to make it go with this new JS library.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the *seek* variable in this way:

```
TIME_IN_SECONDS=(new Date().getHours()*60*60)+(new Date().getMinutes()*60)+(new Date().getSeconds());
var seek = TIME_IN_SECONDS || 0;
```